# Angular 7: Tests fails when <p-contextmenu> is present is html

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my html

```
<p-table #List [value]="orderLists" selectionMode="single" 
    [(selection)]="selectedOrder" [scrollable]="true"
    [(contextMenuSelection)]="selectedOrder" [contextMenu]="cm"
    scrollHeight="50vh" (onContextMenuSelect)="OnRowSelect($event)" 
    contextMenuSelectionMode="joint"
    [globalFilterFields]="['Name']"> <!--  table content -->
</p-table>
<p-contextMenu #cm [model]="contextListContextMenuItems" [target]="selectedOrder"></p-contextMenu>
```

Here's the code to access the context menu:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.logsVisible = false;
    this.contextListContextMenuItems = [{ label: 'View Order History', command: (event) => this.ShowHistory(this.selectedOrder) }];
  }
```

The test is very basic, infact, it is the out of box test template provided by angular:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderHistoryComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
       expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Here's my problem. The test fails with the following error:

```
TypeError: element[NATIVE_ADD_LISTENER] is not a function
at DomEventsPlugin.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomEventsPlugin.addEventListener (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js:1363:1)
at EventManager.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.EventManager.addEventListener (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js:832:1)
at DefaultDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.listen (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js:1142:1)
at DebugRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.listen (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:24357:1)
at ContextMenu.push../node_modules/primeng/components/contextmenu/contextmenu.js.ContextMenu.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/primeng/components/contextmenu/contextmenu.js:120:1)
at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22416:1)
at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22390:1)
at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:22380:1)
at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23316:1)
at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:23548:1)
```

**Update**

PrimeNg Version: 7.1.3

The TestBed.configureTestingModule information:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [TableModule, ContextMenuModule, DialogModule, ScrollPanelModule ],
  declarations: [OrderHistoryComponent],
  providers: [MessageService,
    {provide: OrderApiService, useClass: MockOrderApiService }, 
  ]
})
  .compileComponents(); 
}));
```

If I comment out the `<p-contextMenu>` element, it executes as expected. On the Karma Debug window, I see the context-menu text 'View Order History'. I have not issued any right click event to trigger the display of the context-menu.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're using primeng, which version is in your package.json?
Also can you show the configureTestingModule from your spec? It should look something like 

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [OrderHistoryComponent],
      imports: [TableModule, ContextMenuModule],
    })
      .compileComponents();

Comment: @WesleyTrantham. thank you! Please find updated information.

Comment: Does the rendering of `p-table` depends on data from `OrderApiService `?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan, no, it does not depend on `OrderApiService`, the `orderLists` is an input value from the parent. If I remove the context menu from the item, the tests run as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I have specified a `[target]` in my contextmenu, which, per the primeng documentation says 'Local template variable name of the element to attach the context menu.'. I was referencing an actual variable name. So the binding could never happen. The context menu should have been just:

```
<p-contextMenu #cm [model]="contextListContextMenuItems"></p-contextMenu>
```

without the `[target]="selectedOrder"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]** to ignore child component in you template

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [TableModule, ContextMenuModule, DialogModule, ScrollPanelModule ],
  declarations: [OrderHistoryComponent],
  providers: [MessageService,
     {provide: OrderApiService, useClass: MockOrderApiService }, 
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] // here
 }).compileComponents(); 
}));
```